# "The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context," but user isn't accessing that DB

Tags: sql, security

There are a ton of threads about this error, but I can't find an answer for what I'm dealing with. I have a simple view in DB1 and a user that has permission to select from it. It's not a cross database script. Just a simple SELECT from DB1 only. The server has recently been migrated to 2016 (from 2008) by a vendor and everything was working fine until recently when I would get this error sporadically, but about not having access to DB2. That user is not looking at DB2 at all and again, no cross-database SELECT. This now has also happened to another user. I just can't figure this out. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there, say, any `TRIGGERs` at work?

Comment: No, it's just a simple SELECT statement. No triggers in the database. When I give the login "SELECT" rights to DB2, it works, but I promise, it's not anywhere in the SELECT statement. it's truly baffling and it doesn't happen all the time, which makes it even more strange.